# Jasperreports community version doesnt allow interactive reports?

Tags: jasperserver

I am using jasperreports-server-5.1.1 , and i am using the REST api to integrate jasperreports with my app.

The api for running reports mentions the parameter "interactive=true", but also mentions  - "In a commercial editions of the server where HighCharts are used in the report,
this property determines whether the JavaScript necessary for interaction is
generated when exporting to HTML." .... which i interpret as "only available with commercial edition". Am i right ?

Also, pagination doesnt work.... so is it also allowed only on, commercial edition ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the ad-hoc reporting component is only available in the Pro version (i.e. commercial edition). The community edition is really just a teaser but not really useful for production environments. Did you have a look at [ReportServer](http://reportserver.datenwerke.net)? It's completely open source, allows you to execute Jasper Reports (and Eclipse Birt if you want) and comes with powerful ad-hoc reporting capabilities.